# Angularjs: ng-hide animation with animate.css broken in firefox

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I am using [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). I have following styles for animating a div with ng-hide.

```
.slide-down.ng-hide-remove {
    -webkit-animation: fadeInDown 0.5s;
    -moz-animation: fadeInDown 0.5s;
    -o-animation: fadeInDown 0.5s;
    animation: fadeInDown 0.5s;
}

.slide-down.ng-hide-add {
    -webkit-animation: fadeOutUp 0.5s;
    -moz-animation: fadeOutUp 0.5s;
    -o-animation: fadeOutUp 0.5s;
    animation: fadeOutUp 0.5s;
}
```

Unlike in chrome, `.slide-down.ng-hide-add` does not work in firefox while `.slide-down.ng-hide-remove` works fine.

***[You can see it here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/bzjn6ToLdll018AkYyRI?p=preview)***

Is there anything I am missing to make it work?

### Update

I am using `angularjs 1.3.9` and `firefox 35`.

Answer (score 0):

animate.min.css only contains the -webkit prefix, it would, I believe need the -moz prefix too.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-duration

Comment: i think it works fine in firefox, the problem might be with its interoperation with angular.